# Cartesian product-like in a list

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have the following list:

```
lst = list(
    cat = c("room","shower","garden"),
    dog = c("street", "garden")
)
```

And I would to obtain the output:

```
list(
    list(
        animal="cat",
        place ="room"
    ),
    list(
        animal="cat",
        place ="shower"
    ),
    list(
        animal="cat",
        place ="garden"
    ),
    list(
        animal="dog",
        place ="street"
    ),
    list(
        animal="dog",
        place ="garden"
    )
)
```

For the moment, I use the code below:

```
library(plyr)

grasp <- function(animal, places)
{
    llply(places, function(u) list(animal=animal, place=u))
}

Reduce(append, Map(grasp, names(lst), lst))
```

But there's maybe something more elegant/concise/newer ?

Comment: I think your current method is pretty good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is more elegant or concise and I guess it is not newer but, still, it can be another way of getting the results :

```
unlist(lapply(names(lst),function(x){
                             lapply(lst[[x]],function(y,x){
                                               list(animal=x,place=y)
                                                },x=x)
                              }),recursive=F)
```

I benchmarked my solution and your `plyr` method on a list with 1000 "animals" and 50 "places" for each "animal" (I tried with more than that but it just took too long on my computer...) and here are the results (I didn't benchmark the `magrittr` method because I got an error with my "dummy" list) :

```
base_meth<-function(){unlist(lapply(names(lst),function(x){lapply(lst[[x]],function(y,x){list(animal=x,place=y)},x=x)}),recursive=F)}

plyr_meth<-function(){Reduce(append, Map(grasp, names(lst), lst))}

microbenchmark(base_meth(),plyr_meth(),unit="relative",times=500)

 # Unit: relative
 #        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 # base_meth() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   500  a 
 # plyr_meth() 6.885256 6.844418 5.798948 6.527788 5.475684 7.589215   500   b
```

Comment: Interesting! My method is more functional but far slower! I guess the difference is that I use Map and Reduce whereas you use only one lapply loop and unlist (we are using the same internal loop!)
Thumbs up!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, thanks :-). I must say I was a bit surprised by the benchmark results ;-) but you must be right !

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty close to what the `expand.grid` function does; however that returns a data.frame (which, you might consider using instead). But you convert to a list of lists of data.frames with

```
# library(magrittr)
do.call(`expand.grid`, c(lst,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) %>% split(., 1:nrow(.))
```

which should behave like what you were after